# How to create annotatino to restrict use of functions, similarly to `@Compose`

Tags: kotlin, annotations

How can I create an annotation that restricts where a function can be called, the way `@Compose` does.
I'd like to create a function annotation, let's call it `@WithResource`, such that a function `f` annotated with `@WithResource` can only be called either in another function annotated with `@WithResource` or in the function `fun <T> openResource(block: @WithResource (res: Resource) ->T): T`.
This would ensure that each of the functions with this annotation can only be called in a block executed in `openResource`.
I'd also need to ensure that `Resource` values does not escape those functions, but I kind of hope that if I know how to do the first one, this will give me a hint to do the second one too

Answer (score 2):

Annotations don't provide any magic functionality by themselves. They only add meta data to the code which could be read through reflection or static analysis.

Then we can implement a compiler plugin, a rule for a linter or some other static analysis utility, which will read these annotations and check the code for correctness. However, user of the code has to use that plugin or util for annotations to have any effect.

If this is a very important case for you, you could potentially create such a compiler plugin and then configure the Gradle to automatically use it when building. Then restrictions will be automatically applied for everyone who open your application as a Gradle project. Still, you will miss support in IDE and in most cases this is an overkill. Such restrictions are not supported by the language itself.